# Why is Firefox defaulting to an HTTPS request instead of a Google search all of a sudden?

Tags: firefox

[image]

I'll hit enter habitually and be taken here.  Anyone know the preference do disable this behavior?

[image]

Even a string i've never typed before defaults to a web request:

[image]

Comment: Malwarebytes scan is what I would do right about now.

Comment: "I'll hit enter habitually and be taken here." Where? Which page/image?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio oh, the second image the verzion one - which is what i get if i make a dns request to something that doesnt exist i guess.  firefox defaults to executing `http://testing123` instead of googling testing123

Comment: @metersk If you get a web page then there was a positive DNS response. This seems to be a problem caused by Verizon as they perform DNS hijacking. They respond to all non-existent DNS-requests with the same response that leads you to their server. If Verizon does not allow to disable this redirection you can still change the used DNS server in Firefox or on your PC to one that works compliant to the DNS spec.